# Where does Trip get his six shooter in the Episode "North Star"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In the episode [North Star](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/North_Star_%28episode%29), Trip, T'Pol and Archer all beam down to the surface of a planet with humans from the American wild west. Trip has a period appropriate gun. Where does he get it from?

Comment: Perhaps a personal effect.

Comment: Probably the same place as their outfits.  That I saw just now, neither was mentioned onscreen in that episode, however I think I remember a reference in an earlier one...

Comment: Smells like a deleted scene.

Answer (score 5):

**There are several easy to consider choices to explain how Trip ended up with a firearm during the episode in question:**

- Trip is a gun enthusiast and has a personal firearm created on Earth (or some other planet) with the ability to create such technology using standard mechanical means. Likely the easiest explanation, since Trip made regular visits to Earth. Making ammunition should be able to be made using materials found on Enterprise.
- Using the Enterprise NX-01 transporter, the crew could have beamed a local handgun from the environment to aid in appearing authentic. Since there were no replicators available to the Enterprise (ENT) crew, this makes perfectly good sense for them to have stolen clothing complete with firearms from an unsuspecting homeowner (all done off-camera).

[image]

- The Enterprise could have, what would be high technology to us, but commonplace to them the capability to have created the gun using 3D printing technology. Seeing the Enterprise is an environment needing sophisticated tools and manufacturing, it makes sense for them to utilize a 3D printer to create mechanical devices as needed. As long as the design blueprints are available any reasonable handgun-like device with mechanical components should be able to be created.

[image: World's first fully 3D printed handgun, 2013]

*World's first fully 3D printed handgun, 2013*

Comment: It's worth pointing out that long-duration trips by wet-navy vessels usually include some provisions for textile creation/repair.  There is also likely a small machine shop, responsible for turning out all the minor widgets that might be needed for replacements.  A machine shop able to create ship-grade parts (given time and raw materials) should also be able to produce the parts for a gun, given schematics.  Gunpowder, on the other hand, might be a challenge to create on-ship.

Answer (score -2):

He probably made it, I forget which episode it was when Trip, Reed and other engineering and armory personal built several phase cannons from scratch.

Comment: This answer suggests the same thing as the preexisting answer, but with less detail and no references.  Did you actually have anything to add?

Comment: This was in "Silent Enemy".